# How to call yml script from other yml in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I want to call yml script (which will run end to end test) from another yml script in Azure DevOps.Both yml scripts are in different repositories.

I have used queue build task plugin to run but its not able to find the definition.

Can't find the definition name.

Answer (score 3):

> How to call yml script from other yml in azure devops

You can use the resource specification to provide the location of the repo where another yml file is located. When you refer to the another repo, use **@** and the **name** you gave it in resources：

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

You can check the document [Job and step templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Will check and I will let you know.I am working on it.Thank you.

Comment: @Leo,I will let you know about this issue.Thank you.